# Package Cell Issue on Databricks Community Edition

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

Followed this https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/package-cells.html

**On Community Edition - latest release Spark 3.x**:

> A.1. Created the Package with Object as per the example.
>
> A.2. Ran in same Notebook in a different cell without cluster
> re-start. **No issues, runs fine**.

```
package x.y.z
object Utils {
  val aNumber = 5 // works!
  def functionThatWillWork(a: Int): Int = a + 1
}

import x.y.z.Utils
Utils.functionThatWillWork(Utils.aNumber)
```

> B.1. Ran this in different Notebook without Cluster re-start. **Error**.

```
import x.y.z.Utils
Utils.functionThatWillWork(Utils.aNumber)
```

> C.1. Re-started the Cluster. Ran the import. **Error**.

```
import x.y.z.Utils
Utils.functionThatWillWork(Utils.aNumber)
```

**Question**

Is this an issue with Community Edition? Do not think so, but cannot place it. Observations contradict the official docs.

Comment: @Alex Ott  can you may be shed some light on this pls?